# Flex texItem internal Shadow

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, textinput

I searched a lot but without result...

is it possibile to add an internal shadow to a textInput? using skin or css?

I'd like to have the textInput feel like it has some depth not a simple flat rectangle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a RectangularDropShadow to the skin, turned 180 degrees.